# iterator belongs to what in this code "cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b>::iterator"

Tags: c++, opencv, scope, operators

I am confused with this line of code :

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b>::iterator
```

I know `Mat_` belongs to `cv` namespace and `vec3b` also. But the last `::` operator and `iterator` after that is confusing for me! Is that belongs to `cv` too or it's a function inside the `vec3b` template class?

How does this line of code work?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that belongs to cv too

It belongs to [`cv::Mat_`](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html):

```
template<typename _Tp>
typedef MatIterator_<_Tp> cv::Mat_< _Tp >::iterator
```

> or it's a function inside the vec3b template
>   class?

It's an **iterator**.

> How does this line of code work?

It is used to iterate each element of your `Mat_` object.

Answer (score 1):

It belongs to Mat_ template class